# GetCommandLine linux *true* equivalent

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, equivalent

Similar question to Linux equivalent of GetCommandLine and CommandLineToArgv

Is it possible to get the *raw* command line in linux? The file /proc/self/cmdline is destroyd.

```
./a.out files="file 1","file 2" param="2"
```

prints

```
./a.outfiles=file 1,file 2param=2
```

which is junk

Escaping command line does work for all arguments but the first.

```
./a.out files=\"fil 1\",\"fil 2\"\ param=\"2\"
```

prints

```
./a.outfiles="fil1","fil2" param="2"
```

Comment: How about outputting a space between arguments

Comment: it seems arguments are separated with 0-bytes and quotes are removed. `cat /proc/self/cmdline | tr '\000' ' '` returns `cat /proc/self/cmdline `

Comment: And `/proc/self/cmdline` doesn't contain the "raw" command line; it contains exactly the same information as `argv`.

Comment: This is one of the fundamental differences between Windows and UNIX.  Neither approach is fundamentally right or wrong, they both have different advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do that. The command line arguments are actually passed to the new process as individual strings. See the linux kernel source:
[kernel_execve](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+%2a/fs/exec.c#L1695)

Note that `kernel_execve(...)` takes a `const char *argv[]` - so there is no such thing as a long string commandline in Linux - it's the layer above that needs to split the arguments into separate components.

Edit: actually, the system call is here:

[excve system call](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+%2a/fs/exec.c#L1666)

But the statement above still applies. The parameter for argv is already split by the time the kernel gets it from the C-library call to exec.

It is the responsibility of the "starter of the program" (typically a shell, but doesn't have to be) to produce the argv[] array. It will do the "globbing" (expansion of wildcard filenames to the actual files that it matches) and stripping of quotations, variable replacement and so on.

I would also point out that although there are several variants of "exec" in the C library, there is only one way into the kernel. All variants end up in the `execve` system call that I linked to above. The other variants are simply because the caller may not fancy splitting arguments into invdividual elements, so the C library "helps out" by doing that for the programmer. Similarly for passing an environment array to the new program - if the programmer don't need specific environment, he/she can just call the variant that automatically take the parent process env.

Comment: Specifically, all the quoting and globbing was handled by the shell.  Only if the shell stored the original somewhere the child can access, can you get to it.  And that would be shell-specific.

Comment: Mats, I suggest adding the information from @BenVoigt's comment to your answer (though programs other than shells can also invoke programs, and may build `argv` in different ways).

Comment: @Keith: The parent process doesn't have to be a shell, true.  But then there isn't any command-line to discuss at all, only an array of arguments to `exec`.  Related: `system()` invokes the shell for command-line processing.

Comment: @BenVoigt: There's a command line *in the shell*; the point is that it's not visible to the invoked process.

Comment: Updated a bit. I just hope this is worth the effort... :)

Comment: @Keith: It'd not visible to the invoked process *in any standard fashion*.  I'm sure we could figure out how to write a shell that passes it somehow (temporary file, marked as delete-on-close, and using a pre-agreed file descriptor).

Comment: Conclusion: There is no PRACTICAL & SIMPLE way to get this sort of data to the current process.

Comment: @Mats Petersson: What if the shell just puts everything after the program name into the first string? Also, this behavior actually makes GetCommandLine in Wine incompatible, since the * is expanded. A Windows program might expect this symbol.

Comment: @BenVoigt Or the shell could simply set an environment variable named `SHELL_ORIGINAL_INVOCATION` or something like this. But why would it? Most Linux programmers are okay with shell-processed command line, so there is no demand for this.